# Which is better: PhD in university or PhD in institute?

Tags: phd, university

Are there any benefits of getting a PhD from a university over getting it from an institute?

Note that, at least in the case of Germany, some institutes are considered better than universities and have more strict rules in admission and normally owned by a private organization. So, is a PhD from a governmental/public university better than a PhD from private institute?

Comment: PhD is better at the place where you will produce the best results. Especially in academia, the place of the PhD is somewhat irrelevant, in contrast with _the actual research_.

Comment: The answer to this depends on which field, topic, university and institute.

Comment: You always get your PhD from a university. I did all the work for my PhD at a Helmholtz Center (no teaching duties, good budget), but my PhD is from a university. However, your advisor's reputation and connections are more important for your future career than the institution.

Comment: @Roland I am pretty sure the MPIs are degree granting

Comment: @StrongBad No, they are not. In Germany you can get a PhD only from a university. Regarding Max Planck institutes see point 2 on page 2 in [this document](https://www.mpg.de/9217522/MPG_Leitlinien_Nachwuchs_2015.pdf).

Comment: @Roland Still, it's a difference if your research was at MPI (or any other institute) or not, even if at the end of the day your certificate would have the name of a university.

Comment: @PsySp That probably depends on the field. In my field, having a big name advisor (and, obviously, doing good research) is more useful for your career.

Comment: @Roland Actually that's exactly what I meant: even if the degree is awarded from a university in both cases, the difference is the research done (and the group you were). So, the name of the university/institution does not make a difference, in my field as well (TCS)

Comment: Probably better to do it in a university than in an institute. All those psychoactive drugs will probably make you woozy and not let you concentrate. Also, the selection at the library will likely be poor and they won't have subscription to many on-line journals and archive. I'd say wait till you get out, then have a go at it.

Answer (score 2):

- Do you mean if a PhD from a higher ranked institution is *potentially* better? 
  The answer is: it is better the one which has the potentially better supervisors/equipment at the field of your interest. An institute being more prestigious does not guarantee that will have the best personnel at the area of your interest.
- Do you mean which one is better in terms of the quality of the graduates and the prestige in academia?
  This depends on the actual research of the student. Many stellar students go to the best institute and they don't produce anything for one reason or another. At the end of the day, in academia, what would matter would be the actual content of your demonstrated research and not the particular institute/university.

In short: actual research is ranked higher than institute. Having saying that, in case of ties, these are sometimes broken by the fame of the adviser and/or institution/university.

So: NO, an institution is not *better* a priori since there are many variables to consider. It might be better in cases where what matters is the place of PhD (but I cannot think of any such scenario).